# ASP.NET and Visual Studio doesn't send scripts / style bundles

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, system.web.optimization

I keep having a  re-occuring problem with my code in MVC where when my page loads and I right click to view source, it doesnt have any of my scripts or css in there.

In my .csHTML, it is listed as such:

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/font-awesome.css")
```

Here is the bundle config.

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
                        "~/Stripts/jquery.tmpl.js",
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-ui.js",
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.js",
                        "~/Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

            // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
            // ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                      "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                      "~/Scripts/respond.js",
                      "~/Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.js"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                      "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                      "~/Content/site.css",
                      "~/Content/jquery-ui.css",
                      "~/Content/daterangepicker.css"));
        }
```

This problem is intermittent and is bizarre to me. Sometimes it shows up and then randomly, it does not. This format is the stock template way it is done in visual studio 15.

It makes no sense to me why my css randomly decides not to load.

Here is my web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
        <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.\DB;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
      <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" />
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
</configuration>
```

Comment: `@Styles` and `@Scripts` renders registered *bundles*, not individual scripts.

Comment: This is correct. You can actually just click and drag the script from the solution explorer onto your .cshtml file and wherever on the file you drop it, it will create the script element for you.

Comment: Yes, so why is it working intermittently? Ill add the bundle config for bootstrap and what not. For some reason, it is loading absolutely no style or scripts occasionally.

Comment: I see no issues with your bundle configuration except for the registration for jquery:  "Stripts" instead of "Scripts".

Comment: You say the resources are not there. But does the page render and work correctly?

Comment: The page loads just fine, but there are no lines with the tag <script> or <style>  it just leaves those out so my page is plain html

Comment: May I suggest you extract your script- and style bundle names into public constants, so you can link to these constants from your Razor code also?

Comment: Why are you calling the same bundles twice?

Comment: What versions are you using? .NET Framework version, MVC version etc.

Also, how are you hosting your application? IIS?

Comment: Typo, Im not in my code. When I posted my question, I accidentally hit ctrl+V twice. Edited.

Comment: I am hosting it through visual studio. Just pressing play and loading it into chrome. I added my Web.config file. it could be something to do with the IIS, I haven't configured anything like that. It is not that the <scripts> and <style> lines are in the html and they are just not showing up. Its that the Razor commands are in the code on my project and then when I run it, there is just blank space where it should have left the scripts and styles.

Comment: Visual Studio is not a web host.  You are using IIS Express as the host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double check your IIS settings and clear your browser cache. Once you do that, it should solve the problem. Also, make sure that you are not trying to load into a view that does not have the layout in your case (where your scripts and styles are being styled) because if you layout is null then so will your scripts and styles unless you call them in that view.